# Text file build dependency

Tags: premake

I just started using PreMake to build my project's solution and it is seriously AWESOME!

There is just one thing I still can figure out... I have text files (.oxd) files that are used to generate c++ code for my project. I got the prebuild commands working but the .oxd files in my projects in VisualStudio are automatically marked as Item Type : "Do not participate in build". I would like them to be marked as text files so that when I modify one it triggers a build of the project (and prebuild commands) when I hit compile.

Any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Pre-build commands don't support input dependencies. Take a look at [Custom Build Commands](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Custom_Build_Commands) instead.

The example from that page shows the basic syntax:

```
filter 'files:**.lua'
   -- A message to display while this build step is running (optional)
   buildmessage 'Compiling %{file.relpath}'

   -- One or more commands to run (required)
   buildcommands {
      'luac -o "%{cfg.objdir}/%{file.basename}.out" "%{file.relpath}"'
   }

   -- One or more outputs resulting from the build (required)
   buildoutputs { '%{cfg.objdir}/%{file.basename}.c' }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this feature doesn't work at all in a premake5.